# Почему не удается выкачать сайт целиком?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, wget

Мне нужно выкачать этот сайт www.restoransmaja.lv ,
но почему то данная страница www.restoransmaja.lv/ru/360-tur не выкачивается. А это очень важно для меня, потому что ради этой страницы, я и решил выкачать весь сайт. Мне нужно переместить два панорамных блока на свой сайт, и я решил выгрузить код, чтобы разобраться в нем. 
Но ловлю такую ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю почему так происходит, ведь я точно выгружаю все файлы. Для этого использую wget и такую команду

```
wget -r -k -l 10 -p -E -nc http://www.restoransmaja.lv/
```

Подскажите как возможно решить мою проблему? Возможно я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: wget не всемогущий и не способен выкачивать сайты целиком, только *почти* целиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не сможет wget выгрузить этот сайт полностью (хотя теоретически смог бы). Вся суть в том, что есть flash анимация, которой параметром и передается эта ссылка на tour.xml.

Самый простой способ - скачайте её ручками и подложите в правильное место. Лежит оно здесь `http://www.restoransmaja.lv/static/virtual_tour/*/tour.xml`, а куда выкачивать - понятно по ошибке.

В целом, можно просто сделать свой скрипт для выкачки, который все сделает сам.

Comment: возможно я туплю, но если перейти по данной ссылке, то такой странице нет

Comment: конечно нет. кто же будет звездочку в урле вставлять так просто. Там вместо звездочки 1 или 2. 3 точно нет, другие  нужно проверять.

Comment: точно))) спасибо)